# Javascript code only works in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple JavaScript code to find the current year. It only works in IE. I tried three other browsers . No error just nothing returned.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
   today = new Date()
   var header = (customDateString(today))
   header + ""
   document.write(header)

      </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: customDateString is what?

Comment: What is the line `header + ""` supposed to do? You're not assigning the result anywhere.

Comment: Your right I see now that that line is redundant. I copied the code some time ago. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you @bob

```
<script>
    var today = new Date(),
       header = today.getFullYear();

    document.write(header);
</script>
```

Comment: How? It doesn't look like they were trying to just get the current year.

Comment: @MikeC seems to be what exactly what he want, but just changing the date exhibition pattern to an specific one, which can be the `customDateString()` function

Comment: But you don't know what he wants `customDateString` to be so you have no idea if this matches what they want. If they understood that you could just swap things like that out, they would know they could write `customDateString` to do whatever they want.

Comment: @MikeC I just sort figure out based on the thread description **I have this simple JavaScript code to find the current year.**, which my code make at least sense